# Is there a company who will put my document into LaTeX format for me?

Tags: formatting

I have done a theoretical physics research paper up in a different format than LaTeX. It is currently in .pdf. I have never learned how to use LaTeX, but need the research paper put into LaTeX format immediately. Can anyone direct me to a company or a service which will type up and put my document into LaTeX format for me?

Comment: I can help You. Send me an email. barrientosloayza@gmail.com
You can watch My work here: https://doctrinalex.blogspot.com/p/publicaciones_7.html?m=1

Comment: https://www.latextypesetting.com/ might help you. I am *NOT* affiliated with it, for sure!

Comment: troubleshooting-tex.de (belongs to one of our active tex.sc users) might also help you.

Comment: If you documents contain a lot of complex diagrams that must be redrawn then you will be charged more.

Comment: What format is your document in currently?

Comment: TUG has a list of [Consulting and production services](https://tug.org/consultants.html)

Comment: @barbarabeeton You beat me to it. Just as well as I was only going to list names and emails/websites.